# Sintaxis de selectores en CSS

Tags: css3

Tengo una duda con la sintaxis de los selectores. Me explico...

Si yo escribo `p.miclase{}`, y declaro las propiedades del selector, estoy declarando las propiedades para el html que forme parte de un párrafo y se encuentre afectado por la clase "miclase".

En cambio, si yo me encuentro en la hoja de estilos el código `.miclase p{}` no tengo claro qué debo interpretar y cómo se lee ese código. Esa es mi duda.

Comment: ¿Has leido la documentación o indagado algo?  Esta pregunta require buscar informacion. Si tienes dudas *rapidas* como esta, siempre puedes preguntar en el [chat]. Un saludo

Comment: Son selectores, te recomiendo ver ejemplos de cada uno. Este es bastante completo de https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Answer (score 3):

Esa sintaxis hace referencia a elementos `<p>` que sean [descendientes](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/descendant) de otro que tenga la clase `miclase`.

```css
p em {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Hola <em>a todos</em> los que estáis aquí</p>
<p>Hola <u>a <em>todos</em> de</u> nuevo</p>
```

Añado un ejemplo adicional facilitado por [Kiko_L](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/78966/kiko-l) para ver la jerarquía de CSS ([ir al original](https://jsfiddle.net/Kiko_L/38rqsa7u/)):

```css
.miClase {
  background-color: green;
}
.miClase p {
  background-color: red;
}
p.miClase {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="miClase">
  Div con clase
  <br/>
  <p>
    Párrafo dentro de div
  </p>
  <p class="miClase">
    Párrafo dentro de div con clase
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok. Entendido. Muchas gracias

Comment: He agregado un ejemplo para que lo veas en funcionamiento. Es diferente a `>` que hace referencia a un descendiente directo (hijo).

Comment: Añado otro pequeño ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/Kiko_L/psguenw3/5/

Comment: @Kiko_L te doy consentimiento para modificar mi respuesta. Siéntete libre de [editar mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/149086/edit) y que quede constancia de tu aporte. Validaré tu edición si no tienes reputación suficiente para hacer la edición directa.

Comment: Gracias @Kiko_L , he modificado un poco más la respuesta para que aparezca una referencia a tu perfil, al original, y mantener una copia del ejemplo dentro de stackoverflow.